# Stub Node.js utility function called from a callback (Sinon and Agenda)

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai, sinon, agenda

I'm using agenda for background jobs and I'm trying to test the define method to ensure 1.) agenda.define is called and 2.) a method inside of agenda.define (triggerSend) is called.

I've included the four files I'm using to make this test: 1.) the agenda job definition 2.) triggerSend utility function 3.) sinon stubs 4.) the actual test. I will very much appreciate any and all help you can offer!

As is, agenda.define is being called twice and I can see logs for triggerSend being called twice. The first triggerSend shows a job object, the second triggerSend log shows `undefined`.

I would like to figure out how I can accurately capture agenda.define **and** triggerSend being called, using sinon.

**agenda/campaigns/jobs/test.js** (the job with agenda.define):

```
const triggerSend = require('../../../campaign/trigger.js');

module.exports = function(agenda) {
    agenda.define('test', function(job,done){
        console.log("agenda.define called!");
        triggerSend(job)
        .then(done).catch(done);
    });
}
```

**campaign/trigger.js** triggerSend utility function called in agenda.define:

```
module.exports = async function(job) {
    console.log("triggerSend for job: ", job);
    // Legacy procedural code
}
```

**fixtures/stubs/index.js**

```
const sinon = require('sinon');

module.exports = {
    DefineAgenda: function(agenda, jobMock) {
        return sinon.stub(agenda, 'define').callsFake(function(job, done) {
            /*
            *This is to call the function (job, done) callback from agenda.define,
            *it results in triggerSend being actually called (not the stub) but it
            *also results in agenda.define being called twice.
            */
            return arguments[1](jobMock, done);
        });
    },
    TriggerSend: function(triggerSend, jobMock) {
        return sinon.stub(triggerSend, 'default').callsFake(function(job) {
            console.log("triggerSend arguments: ", arguments)
            return arguments[1](jobMock);
        });
    }
}
```

**test.test.js:**

```
const chai = require("chai");
const expect = chai.expect;

const agenda = require('../../../modules/agenda').campaignInstance();
const triggerSend = require('../../../campaign/trigger.js');
const triggerSendObj = { default: triggerSend };

const DefineAgenda = require('../../../fixtures/stubs').DefineAgenda;
const TriggerSend = require('../../../fixtures/stubs').TriggerSend;
const jobMock = require('../../../fixtures/mocks/jobs').campaign;

const testJob = require('../../../agenda/campaigns/jobs/test.js');

describe('Campaign agenda.define', function() {
    before(function() {
        this.DefineAgendaStub = DefineAgenda(agenda, jobMock);
        this.TriggerSendStub = TriggerSend(triggerSendObj, jobMock);
    });

    it('is called', async function() {
        //call agenda job for test
        testJob(agenda);

        //assertions
        expect(agenda.define.called).to.be.true;
        expect(triggerSendObj.default.called).to.be.true;
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Capture agenda.define is easy, but capture triggerSend being called is not. It requires preparation.

I am agendajs user and this example on how I do it, using piece of your code that I modify a little bit to make it easier to test.

For this test, I use packages: [mongodb-memory-server](https://github.com/nodkz/mongodb-memory-server) (in order for agenda to work, need mongodb server), [mongodb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb) (as mongo client), [agenda](https://github.com/agenda/agenda), chai, sinon, and [delay](https://www.npmjs.com/package/delay) (need to make sure that expect run after additinal time).

There are 3 files in the directory:

1. trigger.js, which provides async function definition that called when job run;
2. test.js, which provides function that define 'test' job;
3. trigger.test.js, which provide test spec to check whether agenda.define called or not, and whether async function inside trigger.js get called or not when 'test' job run.

```js
// File: trigger.js
module.exports = {
  send: async () => {
    console.log('Trigger Send');
    return Promise.resolve(true);
  }
};
```

```js
// File: test.js
const trigger = require('./trigger.js');

module.exports = function(agenda) {
  // Define a job name: test, as async job using done.
  agenda.define('test', function(job, done) {
      trigger.send(job).then(done);
  });
}
```

```js
// File trigger.test.js
const { MongoMemoryServer } = require('mongodb-memory-server');
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
const Agenda = require('agenda');
const { expect } = require('chai');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const delay = require('delay');

const testJob = require('./test.js');
const trigger = require('./trigger.js');

describe('Agenda test', function () {
  let mongoServer;
  let mongoClient;
  let sandbox;
  let agenda;

  before(async function () {
    mongoServer = new MongoMemoryServer();
    // Get mongo uri from memory server.
    const mongoUri = await mongoServer.getUri();
    // Get client.
    mongoClient = new MongoClient(mongoUri, {
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });
    // Connect to database.
    await mongoClient.connect();
    // Initiate agenda.
    agenda = new Agenda({
      mongo: mongoClient.db('agenda'),
    });
    // Initiate sandbox.
    sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
  });

  after(async function () {
    await mongoClient.close();
    await mongoServer.stop();
    sandbox.restore();
  });

  it('define called', function () {
    const spyAgendaDefine = sandbox.spy(Agenda.prototype, 'define');
    // Define test.
    testJob(agenda);
    // Expect that spy agenda define get called.
    expect(spyAgendaDefine.calledOnce).to.equal(true);
    // To make sure that the defined job name: test.
    expect(spyAgendaDefine.args[0][0]).to.equal('test');
  });

  it('triggerSend run', async function () {
    const spyTriggerSend = sandbox.spy(trigger, 'send');
    // Job name test has define above.
    // Start agenda properly.
    await agenda.start();
    // Run test job now.
    await agenda.now('test');
    // Need to add next tick delay.
    await delay(5);
    // Stop agenda properly.
    await agenda.stop();
    // Expect trigger send get called once.
    expect(spyTriggerSend.calledOnce).to.equal(true);
  });
});
```

When I run it using mocha at terminal:

```
$ npx mocha trigger.test.js 


  Agenda test
    ✓ define called
Trigger Send
    ✓ triggerSend run


  2 passing (109ms)
```

**109ms**, quite quick, right? Start up mongodb server in memory will not slow you down. :D

**Notes:**

- *before* function needed to run mongodb server, connect to mongodb server, initialize agenda properly, and initialize sinon sandbox.
- *after* function needed to close mongodb connection, shutdown mongodb server, and restore sinon sandbox. This is needed in order test runner not to hang and wait for timeout.